# What's the difference between module and driver?

Tags: linux

I'm a linux newbie.Today when I try to connect USB-convert-to-serial-port .I should install module or driver or both of  them? Can any one explain what is module and what is driver in simple words and pictures are perfered

Comment: *pictures are perfered* - We like pictures, too. They help us understand, what you mean. Please post screenshots or the text of the exact message that you get.

Comment: @user99572isfine I just what to know the difference  between the kernel module and driver which are just terms I think.

Answer (score 1):

In the easiest way I can think:

a module is a "piece of software", of any kind. it is a part of the main kernel, not a "user program".
a driver is a "piece of software" of one specific kind: it is needed to communicate with hardware components.

a "driver" IS a kind of module.

Answer (score 0):

Drivers are the firmware required by the OS to actively use the hardware on your system. Modules are like add-ons in Firefox (or chrome) where they give you more/different software functionality.